# Drag and drop of sprites in cocos2d 2.0.4

Tags: cocos2d-x

can you any one help me out regarding swapping the sprites position while drag and  drop with mouse in c++ using cocos2d 2.0.4.

```
 CCSprite *splash=CCSprite::create("Level3.png");
   splash->setPosition((200,500));
    this->addChild(splash,1);

    CCSprite *splash1=CCSprite::create("Level2.png");
   splash1->setPosition((300,500));
    this->addChild(splash,1);

    CCSprite *splash=CCSprite::create("Level3.png");
   splash->setPosition((200,500));
    this->addChild(splash,1);

    CCSprite *splash1=CCSprite::create("Level2.png");
   splash1->setPosition((300,500));
    this->addChild(splash,1);
```

Swapping with drag and drop operation with mouse

Answer (score 0):

I think you know about handling touches. To swap follow these steps.

- From wherever you start Dragging copy that sprite. (You have getTexture in CCSprite which you can use it to create new CCSprite)
- Wherever you are Dropping store address of texture of that Sprite.
- Change texture that sprite by Dragging Texture (Again use getTexture and setTexture methods)
- And wherever you started Dragging use setTexture method using stored Texture Address in step 2.
- Finally you have to remove Sprite which is being dragged.

Answer (score 0):

For Cocos2d-x v 2.0.4 it wasn't as advised (due to speed issues) to create events on each individual `cocos2d::CCSprite*`.

One solution would be to store your `cocos2d::CCSprites*` in a `std::vector<cocos2d::CCSprite*>` and have your `cocos2d::Layer` respond to touch events. When the `cocos2d::Layer*` receives and event, loop through your `std::vector<cocos2d::CCSprite*>` and see which `cocos2d::CCSprite*` contained the touch and then act upon it. (checking the bounding box).

You can add touch to your `cocos2d::Layer*` by subclassing `public cocos2d::CCLayer` and `cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate` as well as overriding a few functions like:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
using namespace cocos2d;
class MyLayer : public cocos2d::CCLayer, public cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate 
{
    public:
        virtual void onEnter();
        virtual void onExit();
        virtual bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
        virtual void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
        virtual void ccTouchEnded(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
};
```